# apache serverをstopしてもrunningになる

Tags: apache

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

画像の通り、apache web serverだけstopしてもまた勝手にrunnningとなります。

ネットで記事を見て回ってますが原因が特定できません。

apache web serverに何が起きているのでしょうか。

お手数おかけしますが、ご回答頂けると幸いです。

宜しくお願いします。

iMac (21.5-inch, Late 2013)

Answer (score 0):

httpd.confの

'#' Virtual hosts
'#' Include etc/extra/httpd-vhost.conf

をコメントアウトするとなぜかapacheがrunnning状態になる。

'#' を先頭につけたらapacheがstopするようになりました。